# heroku postgresql wih multiple users and permissions

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

For security reasons i have a heroku project that should access a heroku postgresql database but user can only access some tables.

How can i do this on heroku postgresql?

The only way i can think of doing this is:

- creating a web project with a postgresql dev addon. this will create a new db in a HEROKU_COLOR_X url;
- creating another web project with another postgresql dev addon multiple times so that this HEROKU_COLOR_* is same as previous HEROKU_COLOR_X;
- login in HEROKU_COLOR_X with user_2 (admin) create some tables as user_2 and grant access to user_1 for some tables only.

this will result in same db host (HEROKU_COLOR_X) and 2 user/pass (user_1 for web project access and user_2 for db full access).

.. but is there any better solution?

best,

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about your theory but unfortunately, the [Heroku Postgres docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions) state:

> You cannot create or modify databases and roles on Heroku Postgres.
>   The SQL below is for reference only.

I'd love it if this restriction could be changed or worked around as granular permissions are a security essential.

Answer (score 2):

gerryster's answer is no longer accurate as Heroku have now released support for multiple roles https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials This should cover the OP's use case of restricting access to certain tables.